# Make Word Like Vim

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, vim

I really like Vim and its keyboard commands, but I need the formatting of Word 2011 (mainly because TextEdit only uses 1.25 in. margins, and I need 1 in.). How can I make Word's text-entry as Vim-like as possible?

Comment: Wow. Just wow. +1 for this poor, lost Linux soul. I hope he finds his way back home.

Comment: (ok ok, I kid you maybe a little ;) )

Comment: @bb010g: so all you want to fix is how the text from within vim is printed?

Comment: try this http://www.viemu.com/

Comment: @akira That would work: I just need custom font, margins, bolding, emphasis, and line spacing. (Markdown compatibility would be a plus.) Compatibility with Word isn't absolutely required. I would just use Vim, Markdown HTML export, and TextEdit to do some basic formatting, but TextEdit only does 1.25 in. margins, and I need 1 in.

Comment: Have you considered using LaTeX instead of Word?

Comment: LaTeX, thought I'm not familiar. :p

Comment: @Oops is that really working on osx?

Comment: so you want live in both world : paradise and hell ? It's not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just need the 1" margins, follow @tonyk's advice: write in markdown, use pandoc to convert to ODT or RTF and open in Word or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/). Sure, LibreOffice is bleh, but it isn't bad if you are just using it to tweak final formatting.

Or just use pandoc's markdown2pdf to convert to PDF, and use a custom latex template with `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` in the preamble.

If you really want to use Word 2011 but make it feel like vim, you might try [Quickcursor](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor). Not sure what happens when things get complex, but should work with simple text.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to write your documents in Markdown, then use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert it to ODT, which you should be able to open and style in Word 2011.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en) has four different vi "modes" that you can turn on to get some vi bindings in most applications. They each support different bindings (but are all basic compared to a real MacVIM/VIM editor). You can see the different bindings [here](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html.en). I personally use "Ubiquitous VIM Mode" on occasion to get Normal Mode commands like dd, dw, yy, etc.

Also, I haven't personally tried it, but [viWord](http://dready.org/projects/viWord/) promises the basics using a Word template.

Note that [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) (someone listed it in the comments) is not available for the Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The cross references below are also informative:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586355/vim-for-word-or-something-like-it?answertab=votes#tab-top

and

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5s0kxh/word_processor_with_vimlike_shortcuts/

Comment: Just links to external content would be more appropriate as a comment.  Link-only answers tend to attract downvotes.

Comment: just no........